# Can I use select statement with check constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, constraints

My table is parent-child table where it includes two columns. The first column is `ID` which is auto number. The other column is `ParentID` which has the special conditions. If the row is parent the `ParentID = 0` otherwise it should be related to a ParentID row. For example:

```
**ID** | **ParentID**
---------------------
1        0
2        0
3        2
4        [it can be 0 or 1 or 2 NOT 3]
```

The ParentID depends on the ID column, if the ID includes ParentID = 0 then the ParentID can be that ID.

The question is can i do something like this??

```
constraint ParentID_ck ckeck(ParentID in(0, select ID from table where ParentID = 0;))
```

Or I should use other solution such as PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
--Somthing..
BEGIN
--Somthing..
END;
```

And put it inside the check constraint.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement this constraint with ***combination of foreign key constraint and a trigger*** 
You may use a null-able foreign key from the table to itself.`(parentID == null shows the root nodes)`.
For the part of `select ID from table where ParentID = 0 (null)` of the constraint you may [use a after insert or update DML trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i6052), some trigger examples could be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
insert into TABLE_NAME(PARENT_ID,ID)
(select <THE_PARENT_ID>, <ID> from DUAL where 
  exists (select 1 from TABLE_NAME where PARENT_ID = <THE_PARENT_ID>))
```

So that those PARENT_ID's which are actually not in the TABLE_NAME would not be inserted.

Comment: I need to limit the user on that constraint. Where the user cannot insert any row opposed that condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by fixing your data model first. Your table has two kinds of entities - Parents and Children. Create a separate table for your Parents, then you can use ordinary referential constraints.

Comment: Is there another solution to limit it inside one table?

Comment: Yes (he said, grudgingly), you *could* serialize each insert/update/delete and check it with triggers, but when a simpler and better performing solution exists, why not use it?

Comment: The task is like this. Thanks